# SQL Server MaxDop does not generate Parallelism

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parallel-processing, sql-execution-plan

In SQL Server 2008, I've added `OPTION (MAXDOP 4)` to my query.

However, there is no "Parallelism" step in estimated execution plan.

Does it mean that SQL Server chooses not to execute the query in parallel even if I say that "`MAXDOP 4`"?

How can I force SQL Server to use parallelism?

Answer (score 5):

`OPTION (MAXDOP 4)` is used to limit CPU during execution.

if you want to force SQL Server to use parallelism you can do the following. `OPTION(RECOMPILE, QUERYTRACEON 8649)` you can read more about it http://web.archive.org/web/20180404164406/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/23/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.aspx

Answer (score 2):

MAXDOP is *maximum* degree of parralelism.

Some queries cannot use parrallel processing (example Selects with ORDER BY).

Parrelelism also adds some overhead. SQL Server will not use it unless it sees it as necessary (using Statistics).

Answer (score 1):

From `SQL Server 2016 CU2` you could use undocumented query hint:

```
SELECT ...
-- rest of the query
option(use hint('ENABLE_PARALLEL_PLAN_PREFERENCE'));
```

More info:

http://www.queryprocessor.com/how-to-get-a-parallel-plan/

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/714968/provide-a-hint-to-force-generation-of-a-parallel-plan